# Getting different status code using Laravel PHPUnit

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

- Laravel 5.0
- PHPUnit 4.8.24

If I visit my homepage route('/') in browser chrome shows me **status-code 200** OK

But when I check with PHPUNIT

```
$response = $this->call( 'GET', '/' );
var_dump( $response->getStatusCode() );
```

It returns **int(500)** why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be multiple reasons for that for example incorrect database connection. You should run:

```
$response = $this->call( 'GET', '/' );
var_dump($response->getContent());
```

or verify error log to see what's the exact problem